# Staged unrelated files when pull request encounter conflicts

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, conflict

I create a branch and make some changes in my codes and checkout to master branch and did merge request from the created branch and after this process when I request pull from origin got a conflict and many none related files come into my staged files list and automatically delete some files that I never touched them

can you help me?

Comment: do you use a _fancy_ editor like eclipse or idea that touches things everywhere?

Comment: I use visual studio and vs code